# Что означает return \

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста какую функцию несёт символ \ в return .Я знаю что это оператор деления но не редко встречается именно в return.

Comment: Нередко? Ни разу не встречал. Приведите пример. И это НЕ оператор деления. Оператор деления пишется наоборот - /

Comment: Там, наверно, что-то на следующую строчку перенесено. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16060238/7485582

Comment: @КириллМалышев что там в ретурне переносить-то... мож ещё спецсивол какой в строке

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего это перенос строки, так как по PEP8 нельзя делать очень длинные строки, можно пользоваться переносом строки, чтобы продолжать написания выражения.

Пример использования:

```
def f():
...     return [i * j for i in range(10) \
...             for j in range(10)]
```

Comment: Если выражение обернуто в скобки (в том числе в квадратные, как в вашем примере), то переносить строки можно без этого обратного слеша.

Answer (score 1):

**PYTHON:**

символ обратного слэша указывает на продолжение строки, то есть заставляет линию и следующую строку вести себя так, как если бы это всё было одной строкой.

```
return 1900 < year < 2100 and 1 <= month <= 12 \
   and 1 <= day <= 31 and 0 <= hour < 24 \
   and 0 <= minute < 60 and 0 <= second < 60
```

```
GRAPH1 = Graph(edgesdict = \
           [{NAME:'e1',  VAL: 5, NODE1:'Common Area', NODE2:'Stairs'},
            {NAME:'e2',  VAL:15, NODE1:'Entrance Hall', NODE2:'Hospital'},
            {NAME:'e3',  VAL: 7, NODE1:'Classroom 11', NODE2:'Hospital'}
            ],
           heuristic = \
           {'Common Area':
                {'Hospital':17,
                 'Classroom 11':10}})
```

либо экранировать символы (перед спецсимвола ставится обратный слэш):

`'\"atg is a codon, isn\'t it?\" \"Yes, it is\", he answered'`

`path \\documents\\library\\`

**PHP** (ответ по php не по теме, но я с ним лоханулся, написав первым):
Обратный слэш "\" определяет пространство имён (namespace), в которой необходимо вызвать функцию/метод.

[Описание из хабра](https://habr.com/en/post/212773/)

```
namespace myNameSpace;

function in_array($value, $arr)
{
    return 'Local function';
}
$arr = [1, 2];
$value = 1;

var_dump(in_array($value, $arr)); //string(14) "Local function"
var_dump(\in_array($value, $arr)); //bool(true)
```

Если в текущем пространстве имен объявленна одноименная функция как и в глобальном, то ставится слэш, чтобы обратиться к глобальному пространству имен.

Примеры из жизни:

```
if (!\in_array(.....) {}

if (\count($order) > 0) {}

return \is_array($field) ?......
```

Слэш будете ставит сначала по интуиции и по выпадающим ошибкам, а дальше вникните в правила и будет осознанно кодить этот момент.

Comment: Вопрос про python.

Comment: @КириллМалышев извиняюсь. Ответ скорректировал. Пришлите пример с обратным слэшем в методе после return.